# como recorrer un array y remplazar o eliminar elementos en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

una pregunta como puedo recorrer este array y eliminar todas las comas (,) que encuentre en los value, es quiero enviar ese array desde ajax a php para posteriormente enviarlo a la base de datos y quiero eliminar la coma (,).  Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

```
  var formulario = $("#venta").serializeArray();

  console.log(formulario)
```

el resultado en consola es el siguiente

`[ 0: {name: "fecha-venta", value: "2018-11-09"}
   1: {name: "id_venta", value: "54"}
   2: {name: "efectivo-venta", value: "800,000"} 
   3: {name: "inversion-venta", value: "200,000"}
   4: {name: "gastos-venta", value: "40,000"} 
]`

Comment: Buenas, saludos... en si que intentas hacer, cual es la finalidad del caso?

Comment: es quiero enviar ese array desde ajax a php para posteriormente enviarlo a la base de datos y quiero eliminar la coma (,)

Comment: Bueno es facil, solo que debes colocar mas codigo para ver el proceso que realizas y asi poderte dar una idea de como aplicarlo, pero en si debes recorrer ese array con un each o un map, y asi poder tomar el valor de name y value y guardarlo en otra variable, o sino puedes enviar ese array a php e igual puedes recorrerlo y tomar sus valores alla.

Comment: claro amigo es una variable que contiene todos los datos de un formulario

Comment: ahh ya entendí, ahora si pusiste el código bien. Tienes dos optiones enviarlo tal cual para el backend y por medio de php lo recorres y vas guardando cada variable con su valor, o separar cada valor en el js y enviar cada variable con su valor.

Comment: y como eliminaría la (,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer y separar de esta forma:

```
var x = $("#venta").serializeArray();
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
        $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
    });
```